# How to tell windeployqt where to look for dependencies

Tags: windows, qt, windeployqt

How can I tell windeployqt where Qt is installed? On my CI I install only the minimum required dependencies and add the location to PATH, which works for CMake to build the project. But when I run windeployqt afterwards, it looks for the dependencies under c:\Users\qt\work\install\ and fails to find them.

Dependencies are here:

```
/c/qt/5.6.3/msvc2015/bin/Qt5Network.dll
```

This is the content of path:

```
/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/bin/10.0.17134.0/x86:/c/Program  Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x86:/c/qt/5.6.3/msvc2015/plugins/platforms:/c/qt/5.6.3/msvc2015/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/c/tools/ruby25/bin:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/c/ProgramData/GooGet:/c/Program Files/Google/Compute Engine/metadata_scripts:/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/c/Program Files/Google/Compute Engine/sysprep:/c/Program Files/Docker:/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/c/Program Files/CMake/bin:/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/c/Program Files/LLVM/bin:/c/Program Files/dotnet:/c/Users/travis/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin
```

But it fails with this error:

```
Unable to find dependent libraries of c:\Users\qt\work\install\bin\Qt5Network.dll :Cannot open 'c:/Users/qt/work/install/bin/Qt5Network.dll': The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I believe windeployqt looks for an environment variable to find the Qt installation and when it doesn't find any it looks in the default location of c:\Users\qt\work\install. I've tried setting QTDIR, QT_DIR and QT, but no luck.

Comment: You might try to invoke the following configuration script, e.g. `/c/qt/5.6.3/msvc2015/bin/qtenv2.bat` from the command line. Then run `windeployqt` for your application. The script will configure the Qt environment for you, so the tool can find all libraries it needs.

Comment: Do you know what package provides that script? I've looked in qttools and qtbase and it looks like it's not there.

Comment: This batch file should be in your Qt's bin directory, not in the source base.